# How to do a server/guild level

Tags: discord.py

I am doing a command which logs info from one server to a main one, and I would like to count how many times a server has done a log after the "yes" confirmation, and then display it on the embed. How can I do that?
My script:

```py
@bot.command(name="log")
async def log(ctx, name: str, where: str, too: str, time: str, info: str):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour=discord.Colour.red(), title="Confirm Log?")

        embed.add_field(name="Name:", value=name, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="From:", value=where, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Too:", value=too, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Time:", value=time, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Information:", value=info, inline=False)

        await ctx.send("Confirm log? (yes/no)")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

        if msg.content.lower() == "yes":
            await ctx.send("Sent!")
            server = ctx.message.guild.name
            channel = bot.get_channel(794856521100034060)

            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.green(), title="New Log!", description=f'From {server}')
            
        
            embed.add_field(name="Name:", value=name, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="From:", value=where, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Too:", value=too, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Time:", value=time, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Information:", value=info, inline=False)

            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Save to a file?

Answer (score 0):

```py
if msg.content.lower() == "yes":
    some value in a txt/json/db += 1
    ...
```

p.s there's no problem in sending both normal text and an embed in one message:

```py
        await ctx.send("Confirm log? (yes/no)")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        # could just be
        await ctx.send(content='Confirm log? (yes/no)', embed=embed)
```

Comment: And how would I be able to create a value in the txt for a specific server?